# How to prevent function in AngularJS from being executed simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

Newbie to JavaScript.

I have this function, which gets cached resource, and if it isn't in cache then it calls back-end for this resource.

However, the function is called twice, both times right after login. In the result, there are two exactly the same requests send to backend, as the resource is not cached yet by the time the second time the function is executed. The function is called by different modules, but the modules are in the same service.

Is there a way to 'prevent' a function from being executed for another time if the previous execution hasn't finished yet?

In my case I think it could be done in two places - if possible:

```
function doSomething() {

    return getCachedData()
        .catch(function() {
            return getData()
              .then(saveDataToCache);
        });
}
```

or:

```
function getData() {

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.get('https://www.example.com')
        .then(function(response) {
            deferred.resolve(response.data);
        })
        .catch(function() {
            deferred.reject();
        });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to find out what is causing `doSomething()` to be invoked twice.

Comment: Pretty simple: cache the promise. You must expect the value to be asynchronous anyway. As soon as you trigger the first request, *the promise* is the value you'll want to cache. Subsequent calls can return that same cached promise. All calls can `.then` that same promise, regardless of when it was resolved.

Comment: BTW, why use `$q` here? `$http` already returns a promise, no need to wrap that in yet another deferred.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. All right, I'll look into it. As for the ```$q```, it had already been this way, so maybe I will 'clean' it, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for me something like this worked:

```
var dataPromise;

function getData() {

    if (dataPromise === null) {
        dataPromise = $http.get('https://www.example.com/api/'))
            .then(function(response) {
                return response.data;
            })
            .catch(function() {
                return $q.reject();
            });

        return dataPromise;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't see how this helps. What is assigned to `dataPromise` and when? How has `getSomething()` been modified?

Comment: I explored caching the promise. `dataPromise` gets assigned data from the api call through the GET method and is not null anymore, so the promise was resolved. All calls are using the same cached promise. Function `getSomething()` was not modified.

Comment: Sorry, I should have asked about `doSomething()`. In any case, `return dataPromise;` belongs outside the `if(){...}` clause, such that `getData()` returns `dataPromise` unconditionally, whether it is freshly created or not.

Comment: Yes. And if I get it correctly all calls can process the same cached promise, regardless of when this promise was resolved.

Comment: Sounds like you got it :-)